# ValueError shape mismatch

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am learning pandas and numpy on python. I was trying to apply conditional statements to my DataFrame and I encountered a ValueError due to shape mismatch. Please kindly help me to understand why, thank you!

Here is a look of my simple dataset:

[image]

I was trying to filter the DataFrame if the following conditions are met:

area > 8 and area < 10

Here is the result that I have received:

[image]

The results are fine if I print the condition out individually and I couldn't understand why can't the matrix converge to form a single DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here: `brics[brics['area'] > 8]` and `brics[brics['area'] < 10]`.

The inner expression in both cases produces a 5-element vector.  Both of them have the same shape.  The first has 4 trues and 1 false, the second has 3 trues and 2 falses.  But when you do `brics[xxx]`, that selects a subset.  `brics[xxx]` where xxx has 4 trues produces a (4,4) matrix.  `brics[xxx]` where xxx has 3 trues produces a (3,3) matrix.  You can't combine those.

The KEY is that you want to combine these BEFORE you use them as indexes:

```
x = brics[ np.logical_and( brics['area'] > 8, brics['area'] < 10 ) ]
```

And by the way, you made this much harder for us than it should have been because you posted an image instead of code we could cut and paste.

Comment: I see, that becomes clear now, thanks Tim!